# Using a for loop to print each item of a list from an external file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I am writing a program that reads a 2D list from a .txt file, and I'm trying to loop through the list, and print each item in it. I've used a for loop to loop through each item in the list. The contents of the 2D list in the .txt file is:

```
['1', '10']
['Hello', 'World']
```

This is my code so far for opening the file, reading it, and looping through each item in the list:

```
file = open('Original_List.txt', 'r')

file_contents = file.read()

for i in file_contents.split():
    print(i)           

file.close()
```

The output that I get from this for loop is:

```
['1',
'10']
['Hello',
'World']
```

However, the output that I'm trying to get is:

```
1       10
Hello   World
```

Is there any way that I can get this output? I'm not sure how to remove the square brackets, commas and quotation marks. And once that is done, I can't figure out how to format the lines so that they are displayed as they appear in the external file (with the tabs between each item). I'm quite new to Python, so any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting on newlines and outputting in your format:

```
from ast import literal_eval

file_contents = file.readlines() #read the file as lines
for line in file_contents:
    l = literal_eval(line) #convert the string to a list
    print(''.join([v.ljust(10, ' ') for v in l])) #left justify and print
```

Comment: oh my bad I didn't know that. Thanks :)

Comment: This actually isn't quite what I want, because for some reason, the variable a doesn't contain a single line of the list, instead, it contains every other line. I tested this by adding break after print(a) to see what is stored in the variable a. I need the variable a to store only one line of the list because I'm trying to print the list, and format it into columns, similar to a matrix when using numpy.

Comment: if you want it to print every single line indiscriminately you can use the first solution. give me a sample of the input file

Comment: Sorry, I changed my question a bit, and didn't want it to confuse anyone. There you go, its back

Comment: wait did my answer not solve your problem? Tell me whats going on and i'll edit :)

Comment: Ok great! At the end of my question, I show how I'm trying to display the list so it is formatted like a 2D list, however I can't seem to get it to work. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: yeah but could you give me an example of what the input file looks like

Comment: Like not in list form the actual file

Comment: I thought I did, its the first code section in my question.

Comment: Oh its an actual list

Comment: Yes it is. I'm trying to display it in columns, without all the unnecessary characters (square brackets, commas and quotation marks)

Comment: Im getting this as an error: TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much, you've no idea how long I spent trying to figure out a way to do that

Comment: note there can't be any newlines at the end of your file, all lines need to be in that list form