# Displaying and formatting list from external file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have an external file that I'm reading a list from, and then printing out the list. So far I have a for loop that is able to read through the list and print out each item in the list, in the same format as it is stored in the external file. My list in the file is:

```
['1', '10']
['Hello', 'World']
```

My program so far is:

```
file = open('Original_List.txt', 'r')
file_contents = file.read()
for i in file_contents.split():
    print(i)
file.close()
```

The output I'm trying to get:

```
1        10
Hello    World
```

And my current output is:

```
['1',
'10']
['Hello',
'World']
```

I'm part way there, I've managed to separate the items in the list into separate lines, but I still need to remove the square brackets, quotation marks, and commas. I've tried using a loop to loop through each item in the line, and only display it if it doesn't contain any square brackets, quotation marks, and commas, but when I do that, it separates the list item into individual characters, rather than leave it as one entire item. I also need to be able to display the first item, then tab it over, and print the second item, etc, so that the output looks identical to the external file, except with the square brackets, quotation marks, and commas removed. Any suggestions for how to do this? I'm new to Python, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a for loop to print each item of a list from an external file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49910255/using-a-for-loop-to-print-each-item-of-a-list-from-an-external-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Formatting is your friend.

```
file = open('Original_List.txt', 'r'))
file_contents = file.readlines() # change this to readlines so that it splits on each line already
for list in file_contents:
    for item in eval(list): # be careful when using eval but it suits your use case, basically turns the list on each line into an 'actual' list
        print("{:<10}".format(i)) # print each item with 10 spaces of padding and left align
    print("\r\n") # print a newline after each line that we have interpreted 
file.close()
```